# How to logout from windows8 apps using facebook-winjs-sdk?

Tags: facebook-winjs-sdk

I tried using facebook-winjs-sdk , but FB.logout() functionality is unavailable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out the sample yet?

You can find it at https://github.com/Thuzi/facebook-winjs-sdk-sample